# Remove /bin/busybox at build time

Tags: docker, dockerfile

For reasons such as hardening a Docker image, I want local users not be able to use `wget`. Since `wget` is a function of `/bin/busybox`, removal seems appropriate, even if a little drastic, and would apparently work at for and at runtime.

However `RUN rm /bin/busybox` will cause `go` stack traces, when run on top of Kubernetes or locally.

Is there any build time solution?

The example would be

```
FROM haproxy:1.6-alpine

RUN addgroup -S haproxy && adduser -S -g haproxy haproxy
RUN rm /bin/busybox

COPY haproxy.cfg /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

With the HAProxy's default `ENTRYPOINT`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# first arg is `-f` or `--some-option`
if [ "${1#-}" != "$1" ]; then
    set -- haproxy "$@"
fi

if [ "$1" = 'haproxy' ]; then
    # if the user wants "haproxy", let's use "haproxy-systemd-wrapper" instead so we can have proper reloadability implemented by upstream
    shift # "haproxy"
    set -- "$(which haproxy-systemd-wrapper)" -p /run/haproxy.pid "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: Have you looked into *why* removing the `busybox` binary causes exceptions? I wouldn't advise moving forward without having an understanding on that point.

Comment: ...frankly, if your `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/busybox`, that would explain the behavior you're seeing (no future commands being runnable without an error), and thus why you *need* busybox. If you really want to not have any wget binary, you'd want to recompile busybox without it.

Comment: anyhow, the whole reason I had to speculate above ("if [...]") is that you didn't include a Dockerfile in your question reproducing the problem. If you had  a reproducer, we wouldn't need to guess; please provide one.

Comment: Yeah that is true. However I thought there might be a way to remove it when /bin/sh is not needed anymore, say at runtime, without execing into the container. Or at least execing automatically from Kubernetes.

Comment: How do you think `RUN rm /bin/busybox` works? It calls `/bin/sh -c 'rm /bin/busybox'` *within the container*. Thus, it needs a `/bin/sh` to be available.

Comment: It's a trrivial haproxy Dockerfile with a RUN rm /bin/busybox

Comment: anyhow -- yes, this all can be worked around, but I'd consider using more built-to-purpose approaches. Do you need the `execve` syscall to be available from the main program you're running in the container at all? If you turn that off, then it doesn't matter what binaries are available.

Comment: Yeah, bad that would work, except for the following CMD, I suspect.

Comment: I suspect HAProxy doesn't need it. So yes it would be okay. But that will lead to the same problem, no?

Comment: Huh? How would it lead to the same problem, if you turn that off *in the execution chain that invokes HAProxy*?

Comment: Anyhow. Edit your question to contain your "trivial" Dockerfile, and also add the actual stack trace. Details matter -- `ENTRYPOINT /sbin/haproxy` and `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/haproxy"]` are *completely* different things for the purpose of this question, and which one you use or tested with matters.

Comment: Sure. How would and implementation look like? Will do.

Comment: ...in terms of what disabling the execve syscall for HAProxy would look like, depends on what options your kernel is compiled with and what shiny new security features you choose to use. There's capability-dropping, there's SELinux, there's at least one option that adds a syscall mask... in short, without knowing more details of your environment than it's reasonable to dig into here, I couldn't really dig into one here.

Comment: I haven't seen haproxy-systemd-wrapper. How's it implemented? Most importantly, does it need a shell?

Comment: Well I think you broadening this a little to much. I'd say giving attack vectors from unnecessary binaries like wget it's a fair question to think of ways how to remove it.

Comment: Please read the description. It's the default image from Docker Hub

Comment: *shrug*. Again, the right way to exclude it is not to compile it into the system in the first place. If you were compiling your image with Buildroot (instead of using something made by someone who obviously didn't care about minimizing dependencies), you'd have control over each and every binary Busybox can include or exclude.

Comment: Well I am gonna try that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `/bin/sh` is provided by busybox, and your entrypoint *uses* `/bin/sh`, then you need to delete busybox only *after* the entrypoint is started.

A simpler entrypoint definition, which doesn't require a shell, might look something like:

```
RUN ["rm", /bin/busybox"]
ENTRYPOINT ["haproxy-systemd-wrapper", "-p", "/run/haproxy.pid"]
CMD ["-f", "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]
```

Comment: I think the approach is legit. This doesn't work out of the box, but I am gonna implement it and see where it leads.... subsequently return and mark the questions. Thx.

Comment: That works like a charm. I added an edit to include `CMD ["-f", "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"]` so it would work by copy pasting.